# Load Javascript only once per user / browser session

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, modal-dialog

I have this modal that pop up on page load...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  
  setTimeout(function() {
    $.UIkit.modal('#newsletter-20').show();
  }, 3000);
});

</script>
```

It all work's fine but I need it to appear only once per user / browser session...Since I'm a noob I have no idea how to acheive that even after looking into this information > http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Tks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determining whether your user session is active requires server side code. So, using a cookie is most likely the easier solution for you.

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/L2rdbb0f/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var cookieValue = $.cookie("user-session");

  if (!cookieValue || !cookieValue.length) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $.UIkit.modal('#newsletter-20').show();
      $.cookie("user-session", "1");
    }, 3000);
  }
});
```

***Note***: For $.cookie to work, you have to use a jQuery cookie plugin. The cdn link is this - https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js

*But this is optional, if you want a traditional javascript way of getting and setting a cookie, you can use it too. But the jquery cookie way is way simpler.*

Comment: I have added the jquery.cookie.js but when I put your code I get this error : Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Comment: I have changed the first line of code with this >  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  and now it's working...

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into `sessionStorage`? Using `sessionStorage`, you can store a simple boolean flag locally per session, and then test for the existence of that flag before displaying your modal dialog.

The browser will clear the contents of `sessionStorage` when the browser is closed, which means the value is only persisted as long as the visitor is actively using their browser, or until you manually change the data back to a falsey value.

For example:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  

    setTimeout(function() {

        if (!sessionStorage.previouslyVisited) {
            $.UIkit.modal('#newsletter-20').show();
            sessionStorage.previouslyVisited = true;
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: the problem with `sessionStorage` is that it gets lost once you close the browser, but the user session may still be active.

Comment: You could use `localStorage` instead if you want the data to be persisted indefinitely. (The code above would be the same except `sessionStorage` would be replaced by `localStorage`), then when the user logs out you could manually set the `localStorage` value back to a falsey value.

Comment: If the server can invalidate a session without user action, however, you'll likely need to use cookies.

Comment: I have tried this code :  

if (!sessionStorage.firstVisit) {
    $.UIkit.modal('#newsletter-20').show();
    sessionStorage.firstVisit = true;
 }

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  
  setTimeout(function() {
    $.UIkit.modal('#newsletter-20').show();
  }, 3000);
}); 

but I get this error and the modal is not working anymore :

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vrmrrueh2q476ib/Screenshot%202016-04-12%2010.35.35.png?dl=0

Comment: The sample code I provided would need to be inside `jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { // ... });`

Comment: I've edited my answer above to include the full example.

Comment: I have tried this code :  

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  
  setTimeout(function() {
    $.UIkit.modal('#newsletter-20').show();
  }, 3000);
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  

    setTimeout(function() {

        if (!sessionStorage.previouslyVisited) {
            $.UIkit.modal('#newsletter-20').show();
            sessionStorage.previouslyVisited = true;
        }
    }

});

but I get this error and the modal is not working anymore :

Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list